# Characterization of transcendental elements in algebraic function fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I would like to prove this equivalence:

> Let $F|K$ be an algebraic function field. Then $z \in F$ is transcendental over $K$ if and only if $[F:K(z)] < \infty$. (This statement is Remark 1.1.2 from Stichtenoth, *Algebraic Function Fields and Codes*.)

If $z \in F$ is transcendent, then from $a_n z^n + \cdots + a_1 z + a_0 = 0$, $a_i \in K$, it follows that $a_i = 0$, $i=1,\ldots,n$. So with this it should be possible to construct a finite basis of $F$ as a $K(z)$-vector space. But I don't know how.

And if $B = \{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}$ is a finite basis of $F$ as a $K(z)$-vector space I don't know how to deduce an equation like above for $z$.

I would be thankful for any kind of help.

Comment: Do you really mean that? Think what happens when $\lvert F : K \rvert < \infty$.

Comment: @gisma, read Andreas's comment: either you have a serious typo there or else you have an even more serious misunderstanding of some rather basic stuff in fields extensions...

Comment: @YACP, as I get it, OP intends to prove that given a field extension, $F/K$, and $z \in F$, then *the following are equivalent:* (1) $z$ is trascendental over $K$, (2) $\lvert F : K(z) \rvert < \infty$. Now if you take the case when $\lvert F : K\rvert < \infty$, then (2) holds true for all $z \in F$, but (1) holds for none. **PS** Now I see that OP has just added an extra hypothesis.

Comment: Does this change the situation to a convincing one? And yes, I'm new to field theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition $F$ is finite extension of $K(X)$. Now take $z\in F$. We have a tower of extensions $K\subset K(z)\subset F$.

Assume that $z$ is algebraic over $K$, that is, $[K(z):K]<\infty$. If $[F:K(z)]<\infty,$ then $[F:K]<\infty$, so $[K(X):K]<\infty$, a contradiction.

Conversely, assume that $z$ is transcendental over $K$. We know that $z$ is algebraic over $K(X)$. This means that there exist an integer $m\ge 1$ and $a_0(X),a_1(X),\dots,a_m(X)\in K[X]$, $a_m(X)\neq 0$, such that $a_m(X)z^m+\cdots+a_1(X)z+a_0(X)=0$. Since $z$ is transcendental over $K$ not all $a_i(X)\in K$. Now rewrite $a_m(X)z^m+\cdots+a_1(X)z+a_0(X)$ as a non-zero polynomial in $X$ with coefficients in $K(z)$ proving in this way that $X$ is algebraic over $K(z)$. (The coefficient of $X^t$, with $t$ maximal, in $a_m(X)z^m+\cdots+a_1(X)z+a_0(X)$ can't be $0$, otherwise $z$ would be algebraic over $K$ which is impossible.) Then $[K(X,z):K(z)]<\infty$ and since $[F:K(X,z)]<\infty$ we get $[F:K(z)]<\infty$.

**Remark.** Maybe I've missed something as long as the proof of this characterization is considered in Stichtenoth's book as being *trivial*.

Comment: To the second part: Why is $z$ algebraic over $K(X)$, if $z$ is transcendental over $K$? EDIT: I haven't met him yet.

Comment: Now I got it. If $z$ is transcendental over $K(X)$, then $K(z) \cong K(X)$ and $X$ is clearly algebraic over $K(X)$ since $X\cdot X^1 + X^2 \cdot X^0 = 0$ and $X \neq 0$ and $X^2 \neq 0$.

Comment: @ YACP: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @gisma No, you didn't get it! $z$ is algebraic over $K(X)$ because the extension $K(X)\subset F$ is finite, hence algebraic, and $z\in F$.